# how can convert value of an input to md5 via jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input tag like this:

```
<input type='password' id='myinput' type='text'  />
```

And I give the value by jquery like this:

```
var x = $('#myinput').val();
```

I want to give it in md5 decode. 
How can I convert te value to md5? 
Thanks

Comment: http://phpjs.org/functions/md5/

Answer (score 0):

There is no native function to do this in jQuery

use a [Plugin](https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5)